LED lights on PC case one day started to cycle faster, then now they stopped working
I have an Aureox PC case, it has like a bar on front that cycle RGB lights, then a fan cooler on the back with the same lights but with a circular pattern. One day I noticed that the frequency at which these lights worked was faster, like double, then now I turned it on and they both stopped working.
I dont mind if its only the lights, but if it indicates a problem with the power supply or the motherboard then I would want to know.
The PC seems to work fine, temperatures also in range.
The exact model is Aureox Gamer Lynx.

Is there a button on the case which controls the lighting effects? Perhaps that needs to be pushed. (If you'd told us exactly which model case it is, we could have looked at the instruction manual, which is something you should do ;)

This seems to be the case manufacturer's website. As it seems to be an Argentinian company, the descriptions are in Spanish, and there doesn't seem to be downloadable user manuals available for their cases. But the first line of the description of the Lynx case is:

ARGB LED strip controlado por boton o software

Google Translate says it means:

ARGB LED strip controlled by button or software

From this, I would assume that there is probably some sort of RGB LED control unit, optionally plugged into the motherboard, most likely by an internal USB2 cable, and controllable by a small button somewhere on the case.
The controller might simply have switched into a different mode accidentally (from "slow cycle" to "fast cycle" and then to "lights off"), or if it no longer seems to be responsive at all, it may have failed.
The controller is likely a small piece of circuit board attached to some unobtrusive location within the case. One of the Molex or SATA power cables of the power supply will probably be connected to the LED controller, and there will be other wires from the controller to the LEDs, the control button, and to one of the internal USB2 connector of the motherboard. Follow the wires and you'll find it, and also the button that can be used to control it.
If it turns out that the controller is actually failed (and not just become switched to "all LEDs off" mode), you might consider unplugging the internal USB2 connector from the motherboard and the power cable from the controller, just to ensure the failed LED lighting system is unpowered and cannot cause any secondary damage.
Such LED controller boards are often very cheaply built, so the most likely cause (other than the LED mode being accidentally switched) is that the LED controller has failed, and the other system components are fine.

Ah I see, so the going faster and then not working it could be that somehow the mode changed. But how can this happen on its own?.

Since you don't seem to know where the control button is located, it's possible that you or someone else (children? pets?) may have accidentally pressed it. Also, pushbuttons tend to require a "debounce" circuit to avoid creating multiple impulses from a single button press (because of irregularities of switch contact surfaces, etc.); if not well designed, such a circuit might sometimes create a false impulse on power-on (remember, "cheap to manufacture" is one of the standard design goals of chassis extras like this).
